# make addClass reset on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm sure it's just changing one thing, or adding it, but I can't make it work. An image on top of a video slider is supposed to fade away when you play the video. Then, if you click another (they're linked through thumbnails) it will make the image pop back up and fade agisn.

the first part works, but after the first time, it doesn't work anymore.  Can anyone help me? Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nata2ha/dp5wJ/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few serious html and javascript syntax errors that might be causing some trouble.
I properly indented your code in jsfiddle and seems like you have a broken body tag, and two extra closing div tags that are disconnected.

In your javascript, in the videos array, you missed a pretty important quote.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/dp5wJ/12/. When the code is properly indented the erors are very easy to spot with the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-binding `$('#myVid').bind("ended",`... on each click.